# LDAP connection cannot be established after deploying

Tags: c#, ldap

Am testing ldap connection with variety of params. On my local computer works this combination: myserver.lan:3269 myuser@mydomain.myserver.lan
when deploying to docker, any combination says "The LDAP server is unavailable". Devops has checked that there is a connection from docker to active directory. Is there a way to make it work from net core service?

````
private string TryLdapConnection(string server, int port, string username)
    {
        try
        {
            _connection = new LdapConnection(new LdapDirectoryIdentifier(server, port))
            {
                AuthType =  AuthType.Basic,
                Credential = new
                (
                username,
                _config.Password
                )
            };
            _connection.SessionOptions.VerifyServerCertificate = new VerifyServerCertificateCallback((con, cer) => true);
            _connection.SessionOptions.ProtocolVersion = 3; // its necessary to use paging with basic auth type
            _connection.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = true;

            _connection.Bind();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }
        return $"successful connection with params: {server}:{port} {username}";
    }
public string TestLdapConnection()
    {
        //test
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb = sb.Append(TryLdapConnection("LDAP://DC=myserver,DC=lan", 389, "myuser@mydomain.myserver.LAN") + " ; ");
        sb = sb.Append(TryLdapConnection("LDAP://myserver.lan", 389, "myuser@mydomain.myserver.lan") + " ; ");
        sb = sb.Append(TryLdapConnection("myserver.lan", 389, "myuser@mydomain.myserver.lan") + " ; ");

        sb = sb.Append(TryLdapConnection("LDAP://DC=myserver,DC=lan", 389, @"mydomain\\j-cybercubaction") + " ; ");
        sb = sb.Append(TryLdapConnection("LDAP://myserver.lan", 389, @"mydomain\\myuser") + " ; ");
        sb = sb.Append(TryLdapConnection("myserver.lan", 389, @"mydomain\\myuser") + " ; ");

        sb = sb.Append(TryLdapConnection("LDAP://DC=myserver,DC=lan", 3269, "myuser@mydomain.myserver.lan") + " ; ");
        sb = sb.Append(TryLdapConnection("LDAP://myserver.lan", 3269, "myuser@mydomain.myserver.lan") + " ; ");
        sb = sb.Append(TryLdapConnection("myserver.lan", 3269, "myuser@mydomain.myserver.lan") + " ; ");

        sb = sb.Append(TryLdapConnection("LDAP://DC=myserver,DC=lan", 3269, @"mydomain\\myuser") + " ; ");
        sb = sb.Append(TryLdapConnection("LDAP://myserver.lan", 3269, @"mydomain\\myuser") + " ; ");
        sb = sb.Append(TryLdapConnection("myserver.lan", 3269, @"mydomain\\myuser") + " ; ");

        sb = sb.Append(TryLdapConnection("LDAP://myserver.lan", 3268, "myuser@mydomain.myserver.lan") + " ; ");

        return sb.ToString();
    }```
````